# Couldn't find that process type (web) error on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a Django application to heroku, but i keep getting the following error when trying to scale my application

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Error:

```
Scaling dynos... !
 !    Couldn't find that process type (web).
```

I don't understand what am i doing wrong here, my file is called `Procfile`, it is located at the root of my project, here is how i defined it:

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi --log-file -
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

follow this steps

1. remove existing build packs `heroku buildpacks:clear`
2. add them again using `index` option `heroku buildpacks:add`
3. add empty commit and `push` the changes

**OR** try this one step by step

1. remove your procfile
2. git commit
3. add a new procfile with the exact name "Procfile"
4. commit again
5. git push heroku master

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm trying point 2 but i always get the following error: Error: Could not find the buildpack: first. To specify a buildpack, please format it like the following: namespace/name (e.g. heroku/ruby). Also names can
 »   only contain letters, numbers, '_', and '-'.

Comment: @Jack022 I have updated my answer and added second option. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes! Indeed the problem was that my procfile was being committed as procfile and not as Procfile, i re-committed again and it works now!